# Year of date goes wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My current date is 1/10/2015. If I give sql query in codeigniter as below, It also gives date of like, 1/10/2014,1/10/2013..etc.

So where I going wrong?

Sql query in codeigniter:

```
function get_birthdate()
    {
        $this->db->select('fullname as name,avatar,birth_date,user_id',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('fx_account_details',FALSE);
        $this->db->where('MONTH( birth_date ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) )
                            AND DAY( birth_date ) = DAY( CURDATE( ) )
                            OR (DAY( LAST_DAY( birth_date ) ) =29
                            AND DAY( birth_date ) =29
                            AND DAY( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) ) =28)');
//                $this->db->get();
//        echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

        return $this->db->get()->result();

    }
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? What's "wrong" about it?

Comment: There's nothing in your WHERE clause limiting the year to current (or otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

Try this may be help:

```
 function get_birthdate()
        {
            $this->db->select('fullname as name,avatar,birth_date,user_id',FALSE);
            $this->db->from('fx_account_details',FALSE);
            $this->db->where('YEAR( birth_date ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) AND MONTH( birth_date ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) )
                                AND DAY( birth_date ) = DAY( CURDATE( ) )
                                OR (DAY( LAST_DAY( birth_date ) ) =29
                                AND DAY( birth_date ) =29
                                AND DAY( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) ) =28)');
    //                $this->db->get();
    //        echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

            return $this->db->get()->result();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I accept David's answer. Also I got my mistake that I solved it. Here is the another answer.

```
function get_birthdate()
    {
        $this->db->select('fullname as name,avatar,birth_date,user_id',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('fx_account_details',FALSE);
        $this->db->where('birth_date = CURDATE()
                        AND MONTH( birth_date ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) )
                            AND DAY( birth_date ) = DAY( CURDATE( ) )
                            OR (DAY( LAST_DAY( birth_date ) ) =29
                            AND DAY( birth_date ) =29
                            AND DAY( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) ) =28)');


        return $this->db->get()->result();

    }
```